# Does SDL Web support HTTP/2 (CM and CD)?

Tags: web8.5

It looks like only Windows Server 2016 with IIS 10 can run the HTTP/2 protocol. 
SDL Web 8.5 supports these OS / IIS versions.

1. Can the SDL Web UI work via HTTP/2 ?
2. Can DXA work via HTTP/2 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HTTP/2 is fully backwards compatible and transparent to application code.

So: both SDL Web UI and DXA Web Applications should work with HTTP/2 as long as the browser and web server supports it.

However, neither of both has specific support to leverage new HTTP/2 features.

Comment: we are getting   

org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
 java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.sdl.webapp.common.api.contextengine.ContextClaims.getClaimValue(ContextClaims.java:137)

exception while running a jmeter test using HTTP2 sampler.Do you have any idea how we can fix this